# Python defined 'types' - intermediate dev pet peeve

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses, python-object

TLDR: This is a specific question about best approach to coding a common need in Python, of creating non-flat 'types' - one that IMHO (as 3 year intermediate level python dev) is probably the greatest problem I have with 'how do I do that easily in Python'.

For moderators:  I do have specific code and questions at the bottom :D

### Background

**Lets say I'm writing some code and I need a non primitive variable type:**

So in meta code I'd like to define this in my code to use later:

```
MyType = type {
    mouth: bool
    nose: string
}
```

**Now lets say the variable type I need isn't 'flat':**

```
MyType = type {
    mouth: bool
    nose: string
    hair: {
        color: string
        length: float
    }
}
```

Now lets say I'd like to be able to easily (syntax-wise) create instances and reference attributes (again, meta-code):

```
anInstance = MyType(
    mouth=True,
    nose='big', 
    hair=(color='red', length=5.5)
)

if anInstance.mouth {
    print('has a mouth, and hair is', anInstance.hair.color)
}
```

So lets say my first requirement is
Must Have Requirement:

1. **Easily declare a non-flat types**

*NOTE - The goal/requirement is to define the non-flat type in one go - not using composition of defining all the members separately and then composing the final type*

Now lets also say I'd like - not as must have's but Really Like - two other things to get done in my code
Nice To Have Requirements:

2. **Checking at run type for attribute type correctness**
3. **Restriction on my type, so I can't add new attributes arbitrarily**

So:

```
anInstance.nose = 5.5     # -> this tells me when it runs that it's Bad - wrong type
anInstance.chin = 'hairy' # -> Bad too - this attribute isn't declared in the definition
```

### Problem

My opinion and experience:  The above concept (declare non-flat type ...also perhaps with attribute type and definition enforecement) **isn't easy to to in python**

What I mean by 'isn't easy to do' is that

1. There isn't a single standard way to do it
2. It isn't something that is covered much/well/early in most python classes/tutorials etc - *even though IMHO it is a very common code structure requirement*

**However in many (most?) other languages the above requirements - especially only (1) (non-flat composite types) are syntactically and conceptually easy.**

---

...I know that some people will default to responding with:

- python is duck-typed, so just deal with it
- be a Man, and just write it all yourself using class factories
- just use my favourite module/feature/meta-class template model X, Y, or Z or ...*
- just do it with dictionaries, and screw using dot '.' attribute referencing.
- just use a recursively embedded lambda defined default dictionary
- ... ... ...

...all true points - but I would still contend the need for the above **simply** isn't quite there, the huge number of different ways of doing things are a problem and it isn't explained how to do in many beginner/intermediate type guides, even though (IHMO) it's a common use-case need in an app

---

### Not-real-great-solution solution

I can easily meet requirement (1) by embedding a `dataclass` in a `dataclass`:

```py
@dataclass
class MyType:

    @dataclass
    class HairType:
        color: str
        length: float

    mouth: bool
    nose: str
    hair: HairType
```

Likewise, I could use embedded named tuples.  I could also use any number of modules (marshmellow, pydantic, ..., ...).

But - again - my contention/observation - this isn't concise and simple (as it could/should be?), and there are X different ways of doing it, even though (IMHO) it's a common requirement.

### Questions

- For the above type definition, (and optionally, also the attribute checking goals) what methods do people use?   ...what are the pros and cons of the different options?
- Is there a way to do the above - especially just requirement (1) - in a very simple, concise way in python?
- Am I alone in thinking a) this is a common requirement and b) it's not quick and easy to do in Python (compared to some other languages)

Comment: 2 and 3 are problems that come with a non-statically-typed language. [Enforcing them would make Python non-dynamically-typed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#non-goals). If you absolutely want a statically typed language, use something other than Python.

Comment: Yeah I know that - that's why I said they're optional requirements - but common ones, considering the uptake in the use of typing in python.

Comment: "this isn't concise and simple" - what would be a simple and concise way, in your opinion?

Comment: We can debate how enthusiastically a language should adapt to the desires of its users till the cows come home, but according to the BDFL and associates, _"Python will remain a dynamically typed language, and the authors have no desire to ever make type hints mandatory, even by convention."_ There's really no "concise and simple" way to do what you want -- at least as concise and simple as your pseudocode -- given the restrictions of a dynamically typed language.

Comment: Hi Pranav, understand what you're saying, and that's why I said type checking etc was optional - but still, what's the best simple way to create a non-flat 'type'?  that I'd still contend isn't obvious to most people

Comment: @ForceBru - something like the meta code :D ...which is almost as simple as you'd do it in javascript, C, etc.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you don't normally define types like this in Python. You define `class` such and such, define its `__init__` method that initialises instance attributes and then instantiate the class like `MyClass(5, AnotherClass('hello', 'world'))` - and here's the "non-flat" _object_. However, the class itself doesn't care about the types of the data it holds - it's the `__init__` method that's responsible for type-checking, if any, because Python is dynamically typed. If you want to save yourself some boilerplate, use `dataclass`es or your own metaclasses.